# PHP - Increment a value

Tags: php

I'd like to increment a value in a 3-digits format.

For example:

```
$start_value = 000;
while () {
do something;
$start_value++;
}
```

In this way I have this result:

```
$start_value = 000;
$start_value = 1;
$start_value = 2;
$start_value = 3;
```

and so on

instead of `'001', '002', '003'`

How I can accomplish this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a big mistake here. `000` in code is an octal number. Any literal number starting with a 0 in many programming languages is considered an octal literal. If you want to store 000, you need a string, not a number.

```
$start_value = "000";
while((int) $start_value /*--apply condition --*/) {
    do something;
    $start_value = str_pad((int) $start_value+1, 3 ,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) you can accomplish this with:

```
echo sprintf("%03d", $start_value++) . "<br>";
```

Hopefully that is what you were after.

**Implementing it with your code:**

```
$start_value = 000;
while () {
    do something;
    $start_value = sprintf("%03d", $start_value++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this. In PHP there is no concept of datatypes everything is determined in runtime based on where and how it is used.

```
<?php
 $start_value = 000;
 while ($start_value < 10) {
 //your logic goes here
  $start_value++;
 printf("[%03s]\n",$start_value);
 }
?>
```

Output : [001] [002] [003] [004] [005] [006] [007] [008] [009] [010]

So you can do all the calculation. Where ever you want to print the value, you can use printf with format specifiers.!! Hope it helps.